# Vertica insert is ignored

Tags: python, vertica

I'm trying to do a very simple `INSERT` into a vertica table, and it doesn't work: my data is silently ignored.

```
$ LC_ALL=C /opt/vertica/bin/vsql db user -w *** -c "SELECT * FROM footable"
         lastFetch         | ApiPath | response 
---------------------------+---------+----------
 2015-02-07 18:41:42.26069 | a1      | b1
(1 row)

$ LC_ALL=C /opt/vertica/bin/vsql db user -w *** -c "INSERT INTO footable (lastFetch, ApiPath, response) VALUES ('2015-02-07 18:19:32.435001', 'a2', 'b2')"
 OUTPUT 
--------
      1
(1 row)

$ LC_ALL=C /opt/vertica/bin/vsql db user -w *** -c "SELECT * FROM footable"
         lastFetch         | ApiPath | response 
---------------------------+---------+----------
 2015-02-07 18:41:42.26069 | a1      | b1
(1 row)
```

Any idea of what could be going wrong?

I tried with [vertica-python](https://github.com/uber/vertica-python), same result.
I also tried with `NOW()` instead of `'2015-02-07 18:19:32.435001'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default AUTOCOMMIT is off:

```
$ vsql -c "\set"
VERSION = 'vsql'
AUTOCOMMIT = 'off'
...
```

Or commit your changes or define `AUTOCOMMT=ON`.
For my opinion - a second option is better:

```
$ vsql -v AUTOCOMMIT=on -c "\set"
VERSION = 'vsql'
AUTOCOMMIT = 'on'
...
```

or just put `commit` right after INSERT statement:

```
$ vsql  -c "INSER INTO whatever VALUES (...); commit;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I need to add `COMMIT` after a batch of `INSERT` commands.
See https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/vsql/AUTOCOMMIT.htm .

One `COMMIT` only when needed seems better than `AUTOCOMMIT` that will trigger a commit after each insert.